# Twitter boot strap with jade template engine does not apply effect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am trying to apply twitter css to my jade view, however the effect did not show up and as I inspect console, it seems like the browser cannot get the css, it listed 404 , but I am sure that the directory listing is correct, what could be the problem?

```
!!! 5
html(lang='en')
head
    title title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/static/css/bootstrap.css', type='text/css')
  body
    p The open items are as follows:
    table.table.table-striped
      tr
        td "a"
        td "a1"
      tr
        td "b"
        td "b1"
    script(src='/static/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js')
    script(src='/static/js/bootstrap.js')
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you declare that static file on your server ?

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? or just abandon the site?

Comment: This is a problem with node.js routing, not pug or bootstrap.  Recommending closure as this Question doesn't meet MCVE.